# Mysql table insertion stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to insert data into a table whose tablename and values are being passed from the user in the stored procedure.

```
enter code here
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE tableinsertion(IN tablename varchar(20),IN ano int(10))
-> BEGIN
-> SET @s=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', tablename, 'values', (ano));
-> PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
-> EXECUTE stmt;
-> END //
```

I'm calling the function as follows
CALL tableinsertion('account','110')//
But I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Missing spaces

```
SET @s=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', tablename, 'values', (ano));
                                          ^-----^---here
```

which produces the query

```
INSERT INTO sometablevalues(ano)
```

Comment: Still the same error saying you have error at line 3 i.e. SET @s=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', tablename, 'values', (ano));